# Are there are any important differences between these two ways of writing arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

This is a conceptual question following on from a question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512407/how-to-get-the-first-columns-contents-from-a-2d-array/14512494#14512494))  I recently got an answer to. 
I will use a java example to demonstrate my question but I think this should hold for other similar languages (I could not say for sure -hopefully someone can confirm this or say otherwise). Basically I am wondering if there is any subtle difference between the possible uses for following (given how they are initialised):

```
double[] array1D = new double[max]
```

and

```
double[][] array2D = new double [max][1]
```

Assuming that we are initialising the second array to have only one column, is there really any need for the 1D array to exist? Does it have any quality that a 2D array doesn't have, or is it just there to confuse poor souls like myself? Furthermore I would like to know if `array2D` with only one column can do anything that `array1D`cannot?

Comment: Both arrays are the same, the only difference is that using the 2nd way is clumsy (and if I were you I would never dare to use it at least that I want to get fired)

Comment: Please elaborate, I don't want to get fired but I hate doing things without knowing why.

Comment: There's nothing to elaborate. I guess that if you draw an array in a piece of paper and next to it draw a 2d array where the 2nd dimension is a single row you will get your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between array1D and array2D is that in the latter the rows (or columns, however you want to look at it) are individual objects that can be used independently of the entire array.

For example you can pass an entire row to a function, and the function is allowed to modify the row. To achieve the same with a 1D array you'd have to pass the original array, the start index of the row in the array, and length of the row.

Every reference to an object costs 4 bytes, so the memory usage increases with 4 bytes for each element, so it is a waste of memory to use a 2D array for something that a 1D array can do.

Comment: So does that mean it would be a waste of memory to use 2D arrays in the way I have supposed they be used in my question?

Comment: Yes, the program with a 2D array as shown will also use more memory because of the overhead of wrapping each element in an individual array. (Overhead for an array is 4 bytes for object header and 4 bytes for array length. A reference to an object is 4 bytes, so the memory usage increases with 4 bytes for each element)

Answer (score 1):

new double[max] creates an array of doubles (initialized with 0.0) with lengh = max

new double [max][1] creates an array of pointers each of them points to a double array with one element = 0.0

Comment: nicely put. I am guessing this implies more memory getting used needlessly?

Comment: assuming max = 10 then #1 will take ~ 80 +16 bytes; #2 will take ~ 40 + 16 + (8 + 16) * 10.

Answer (score 1):

```
int A[2][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

A 2D array is stored in the memory as follows. Entries in
row 0 are stored first followed by row 1 and so on.

[image]

2-D arrays are represented as a
contiguous block of n blocks each with size m (i.e. can
hold m integers(or any data type) in each block). The
entries are stored in the memory as shown above.Here n represent the number of rows and m represents the
number of columns.

**In Java:**

As with all arrays, the new keyword must be used to allocate memory for an array. For example,

```
 int[][] a = new int[2][4];
```

This two-dimensional array will have two rows and four columns.
This actually allocates 3 objects: a one-dimensional array of 2 elements to hold each of the actual row arrays, and  two one-dimensional arrays of 4 elements to represent the contents of the rows.

```
 +-----+    +-----+-----+-----+-----+
 |a[0] | -> | [0] | [1] | [2] | [3] |
 |     |    +-----+-----+-----+-----+    In Java two-dimensional arrays are implemented is a  
                                        one-dimensional array of one-dimensional arrays -- like this.
 +-----+
 |     |    +-----+-----+-----+-----+
 |a[1] | -> | [0] | [1] | [2] | [3] |
 +-----+    +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

In your case:

```
double[][] array2D = new double [max][1]
```

This actually allocates max+1 objects: a one-dimensional array of max elements to hold each of the actual row arrays, and max one-dimensional arrays of 1 elements to represent the contents of the rows.

Let me know if I am wroung .

Comment: n and m are not indicated in your picture?

Comment: -1 For Java that is wrong, the array for the first index stores pointers to arrays for the second index, which contain the values. In particular, the inner arrays may be of different length.

Comment: @Magpie Picture is for int A[2][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}; And description is for 2d array in general.

Comment: @starblue I was thinking this was the wrong was round too. You clarified this very articulately although I think -1 is harsh when he's gone to an effort and i did open my question to be conceptual rather than language specific

Answer (score 0):

Both will just do the same thing. Moreover you don't need to create a 2-dimensional array when  all you need is just one row. A 2-dimensional array is used when you need to work with multiple 1-dimensional arrays.

Also, I think you need to initialize your 2-dimensional in this way to achieve it to work for 1-d array

```
double[][] array2D = new double[1][max]
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this is 1D array

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

and this is 2D array

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

basically, 2D array can store more data than 1D array, and more complex than 1D array

Comment: saying something is more complex does not constitute giving an answer

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the misconception that it is normal for arrays to have two dimensions.  This is not true.

In programming languages one-dimensional arrays are the norm, while two- and higher dimensional ones are rather rare (I can't remember when I last used one in Java).

Using a two-dimensional array instead of a one-dimensional one would be possible, but it would obscure the meaning of the array and make accessing the array elements more complicated.

Comment: I kind of feel like the 1D array obscures the meaning of the 2D array (if you read my link you I explain why). Moreover, it could have more than 2 columns so is it not misleading that it is called a 2D array or have I missed something there?